Percona pg_tde extension base backup failing
I am just asking here so that someone from Percona  can check if possible.
I have followed below documentation to configure pg_tde in RHEL 8 with PG version 16.
https://percona.github.io/pg_tde/main/
After enabling and configuring pg_tde key provider  and master key . pg_basebackup is getting failed with below error
[postgres@hostname postgres]$ pg_basebackup -D bkp_test -R -X stream -v
pg_basebackup: initiating base backup, waiting for checkpoint to complete
pg_basebackup: checkpoint completed
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log start point: 0/14000028 on timeline 1
pg_basebackup: starting background WAL receiver
pg_basebackup: created temporary replication slot "pg_basebackup_1391250"
WARNING:  aborting backup due to backend exiting before pg_backup_stop was called
pg_basebackup: error: COPY stream ended before last file was finished
pg_basebackup: removing contents of data directory "bkp_test"

In the logs I can see below error.
2024-10-18 07:55:21.132 EDT [1241049] LOG:  checkpoint starting: force wait
2024-10-18 07:55:21.136 EDT [1241049] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 0 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.001 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.004 s; sync files=0, longest=0.000 s, average=0.000 s; distance=16384 kB, estimate=27000 kB; lsn=0/14000060, redo lsn=0/14000028
2024-10-18 07:55:21.205 EDT [1391249] WARNING:  aborting backup due to backend exiting before pg_backup_stop was called
2024-10-18 07:55:21.205 EDT [1391249] ERROR:  invalid segment number 0 in file "pg_tde.map"
2024-10-18 07:55:21.205 EDT [1391249] STATEMENT:  BASE_BACKUP ( LABEL 'pg_basebackup base backup',  PROGRESS,  WAIT 0,  MANIFEST 'yes',  TARGET 'client')
2024-10-18 07:55:21.221 EDT [1391250] LOG:  unexpected EOF on standby connection
2024-10-18 07:55:21.221 EDT [1391250] STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "pg_basebackup_1391250" 0/14000000 TIMELINE 1

After loading shared library pg_tde on server level and configuring master key for specific DB level, I can see below files in base directory that is creating issue. but unable to understand .
./16505/pg_tde.map
./16505/pg_tde.dat

below are the databases with OID.
test=# select oid,datname from pg_database;
  oid  |  datname
-------+-----------
     5 | postgres
     1 | template1
     4 | template0
 16505 | test
(4 rows)

Thanks for your help and suggestion if any.
